# How do read this json file in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have tried this code

```
data_JSON =  """
the data inside json file
"""
```

```
data_dict = json.loads(data_JSON)
```

I have tried this and several others methods ,but still failing to load the json file in pandas.
How can I load the json file into the pandas dataframe?

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Here is the json file

```
{
  "programs": [
    {
      "id": "00646b9f-fec7-4ffb-9fb1-faae410bd9dc-0.1",
      "programID": "3853",
      "orchestra": "New York Philharmonic",
      "season": "1842-43",
      "concerts": [
        {
          "eventType": "Subscription Season",
          "Location": "Manhattan, NY",
          "Venue": "Apollo Rooms",
          "Date": "1842-12-07T05:00:00Z",
          "Time": "8:00PM"
        }
      ],
      "works": [
        {
          "ID": "52446*",
          "composerName": "Beethoven,  Ludwig  van",
          "workTitle": "SYMPHONY NO. 5 IN C MINOR, OP.67",
          "conductorName": "Hill, Ureli Corelli",
          "soloists": []
        },
        {
          "ID": "8834*4",
          "composerName": "Weber,  Carl  Maria Von",
          "workTitle": "OBERON",
          "movement": "\"Ozean, du Ungeheuer\" (Ocean, thou mighty monster), Reiza (Scene and Aria), Act II",
          "conductorName": "Timm, Henry C.",
          "soloists": [
            {
              "soloistName": "Otto, Antoinette",
              "soloistInstrument": "Soprano",
              "soloistRoles": "S"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "3642*",
          "composerName": "Hummel,  Johann",
          "workTitle": "QUINTET, PIANO, D MINOR, OP. 74",
          "soloists": [
            {
              "soloistName": "Scharfenberg, William",
              "soloistInstrument": "Piano",
              "soloistRoles": "A"
            },
            and more
```

Comment: You can't directly load nested data into a Pandas dataframe.

What would be the shape (columns) you'd imagine a dataframe from that data to have?

Comment: can look into pd.json_normalize() or the package flatten_json

Answer (score 0):

Because your example json isn't complete, I'm assuming there isn't more to it than below. You can run the lines of code see the differences in how each method parses. For json_normalize() you'd have to run each nested key:value and merge, where flatten_json does the heavy lifting but you many have to do more post processing to get the dataframe you want

```
data = {
  "programs": [
    {
      "id": "00646b9f-fec7-4ffb-9fb1-faae410bd9dc-0.1",
      "programID": "3853",
      "orchestra": "New York Philharmonic",
      "season": "1842-43",
      "concerts": [
        {
          "eventType": "Subscription Season",
          "Location": "Manhattan, NY",
          "Venue": "Apollo Rooms",
          "Date": "1842-12-07T05:00:00Z",
          "Time": "8:00PM"
        }
      ],
      "works": [
        {
          "ID": "52446*",
          "composerName": "Beethoven,  Ludwig  van",
          "workTitle": "SYMPHONY NO. 5 IN C MINOR, OP.67",
          "conductorName": "Hill, Ureli Corelli",
          "soloists": []
        },
        {
          "ID": "8834*4",
          "composerName": "Weber,  Carl  Maria Von",
          "workTitle": "OBERON",
          "movement": "\"Ozean, du Ungeheuer\" (Ocean, thou mighty monster), Reiza (Scene and Aria), Act II",
          "conductorName": "Timm, Henry C.",
          "soloists": [
            {
              "soloistName": "Otto, Antoinette",
              "soloistInstrument": "Soprano",
              "soloistRoles": "S"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "3642*",
          "composerName": "Hummel,  Johann",
          "workTitle": "QUINTET, PIANO, D MINOR, OP. 74",
          "soloists": [
            {
              "soloistName": "Scharfenberg, William",
              "soloistInstrument": "Piano",
              "soloistRoles": "A"
            }]}]}]}
pd.DataFrame(data['programs'])
pd.json_normalize(data['programs'])

pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['programs','concerts'],  meta=[['programs','id'],['programs','programID']])
pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['programs','works'],  meta=[['programs','id'],['programs','programID']])

from flatten_json import flatten
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in data['programs'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```